# Apache OpenJPA - NamedQuery Exception

Tags: java, exception, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I hava two tables with a manyToMany relation :

```
@Entity(name = "arelation")
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "arelation.findAByName", query = "SELECT a FROM arelation a WHERE a.arelationname = :aname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "arelation.findA", query = "SELECT a FROM arelation a WHERE a.arelationname = :aname and a.bList = :bList")
})
public class ABean{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String arelationname;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = BBean.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "joinAB", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "aID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "bID") })
    private List<BBean> bList= new ArrayList<BBean>();

        .......
}

@Entity(name = "brelation")
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "brelation.findB", query = "SELECT b FROM brelation b WHERE b.brelationname = :bname)})
public class BBean{
    /*
     * private Bean Variables
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private String brelationname;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bList")
    @NotNull
    private List<ABean> aList= new ArrayList<ABean>();

        .......
}
```

No I want to find a ABean with the NamedQuerd arelation.findA like this:

```
public ABean findABean(EntityManager em, ABean a)
        throws NoResultException {
    return  (ABean) em.createNamedQuery("arelation.findA")
            .setParameter("aname", a.getArelationname())
            .setParameter("blist", a..getBList())
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

I set the bList with persisted objects from the database.

But when I want to find the "ABean" i get following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter "Parameter<BBean>('blist')" declared in "SELECT a FROM arelation a WHERE a.arelationname = :aname and a.bList = :bList" is set to value of "[     ArelationName: name0
,       ArelationName: name1
,       ArelationName: name2
,       ArelationName: name3
,       ArelationName: name4
,       ArelationName: name5
,       ArelationName: name6
,       ArelationName: name7
]" of type "org.apache.openjpa.util.java$util$ArrayList$proxy", but this parameter is bound to a field of type "mypackage.BBean"
```

Does someone know why I get this Exception?
I only want to know, if the ABean with this name and this BBeans exists in the DB.

EDIT:
Ok, I know the reason:
The Parameter should be a BBean and not a List of it.
But how can I use a List of BBeans?

Best Regards
Veote

Answer (score 1):

In named query you should use class name when trying to refer to table, try to use this

```
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "brelation.findB", query = "SELECT b FROM BBean b WHERE b.brelationname = :bname)})
```

and the second one is that you do not need to create new object , 
just let it stay `List<BBean> aList;`

hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but I cant SELECT from a bean -> I get an ArgumentEception: Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: An error occurred while parsing the query filter "SELECT a FROM ABean a WHERE a.arelationname = :aname and a.bList = :bList". Error message: The name "ABean" is not a recognized entity or identifier. Perhaps you meant arelation, which is a close match. Known entity names: [arelation, brelation]

Comment: You changed the Entity name from 'ABean' to 'arelation' in the @Entity annotation.